# strange behavior of 3x4 keypad

Tags: arduino, esp32, keypad

hi i tried to use the keypad.h library for sending a pressed key to serial port of esp32 by Arduino platform but it didn't work and it only detected rows. so i tried to write a function for running the keypad but it doesn't work either. the problem is that it doesn't detect the rows for example when i press 4 it prints 1 and when i press 5 it shows 2 and so on. the oddest thing is when i delete the keys 1-3 from void loop keys 4 to 12 work but only one out of ten times here is my code `what might be the problem here ?

```
#include <string.h>

#include <string>

#include <Arduino.h>

int key_scan(void);

int key_scan(void)

{

int s;

digitalWrite(17,HIGH);

delay(10);

if (digitalRead(25)) return 1;

else if (digitalRead(23)) return 2;

else if (digitalRead(22)) return 3;

digitalWrite(17,LOW);

digitalWrite(18,HIGH);

delay(10);

if (digitalRead(25)) return 4;

else if (digitalRead(23)) return 5;

else if (digitalRead(22)) return 6;

digitalWrite(18,LOW);

digitalWrite(19,HIGH);

delay(10);

if (digitalRead(25)) return 7;

else if (digitalRead(23)) return 8;

else if (digitalRead(22)) return 9;

digitalWrite(19,LOW);

digitalWrite(21,HIGH);

delay(10);

if (digitalRead(25)) return 10;

else if (digitalRead(23)) return 11;

else if (digitalRead(22)) return 12;

digitalWrite(21,LOW);

return 0;

}

void setup()

{

 

  pinMode(17,OUTPUT);

  pinMode(18,OUTPUT);

  pinMode(19,OUTPUT);

  pinMode(21,OUTPUT);

  pinMode(22,INPUT);

  pinMode(23,INPUT);

  pinMode(25,INPUT);

   

  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("salam");

  Serial.println("esp32");

 

}

void loop()

{

 

  int s;

 

  if (key_scan()==1)

   {

   Serial.print(1);

   delay(200);

   }

   else if (key_scan()==2)

   {

   Serial.print(2);

   delay(200);

   }

   else if (key_scan()==3)

  {

  Serial.print(3);

   delay(200);

  }

    else if (key_scan()==4)

   {

  Serial.print(4);

   delay(10);

   }

   else if (key_scan()==5)

     {

   Serial.print(5);

   delay(100);

   }

   else if (key_scan()==6)

   {

   Serial.print(6);

   delay(100);

   }

   else if (key_scan()==7)

  {

   Serial.print(7);

   delay(100);

   }

    else if (key_scan()==8)

  {

   Serial.print(8);

   delay(100);

   }

    else if (key_scan()==9)

  {

   Serial.print(9);

   delay(100);

   }

      else if (key_scan()==10)

  {

   Serial.print('+');

   delay(100);

   }

        else if (key_scan()==11)

  {

   Serial.print('-');

   delay(100);

   }

        else if (key_scan()==12)

  {

   Serial.print('=');

   delay(100);

   }
```

[image]

Comment: It might be a hardware problem, maybe you wired something incorreclty. We can only guess.

Comment: Rather than do a scan of the keypad in every if statement in the loop, why don't you do one scan of the keypad at the beginning, then store the returned value in a variable. Then check the value of the variable to decide what to do.  The way you have written the code, there will be very large delays involved scanning for each key.

Comment: show which GPIOs are connected to the columns and rows of the keypad.

Comment: `it doesn't detect the rows` ... your code has 4 outputs and 3 inputs ... it detects columns, not rows

Comment: @Justme i checked the hardware with a multimeter there is no problem

Comment: @jstola im sorry i meant it doesn't distinguish between different rows

Comment: @HandyHowie the delays in the loop are for debouncing and they are in milliseconds

Comment: @HandyHowie the rows are connected to pin 17 ,18,19,21 and the columns to pin 22,23,25

Comment: It's kinda stupid that you scan the keys every time to check the key. Check all the keys... it was 3. Was it 1? No... check all the keys again... it was 3. Was it 2? No.... check all the keys again.... it was 3. Was it 3? Aha! It was 3! Print 3!

Answer (score 2):

If you press any key then the scan function leaves the corresponding output scan pin high.

So when the matrix input is read the next time, there might be two output pins high and it returns wrong button code from wrong row.

Answer (score 0):

my problem is solved now and the code works. the problem was that i only made one row output pin high and other output pins were floating. i gave a value to each of 4 output in every scan and now it works like a charm

Comment: The output was not floating. See my answer which describes what the problem was.